# How to return back to intent after sending sms using native sms composer

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using below code for sending sms using native sms composer

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.putExtra("address", "1234567890");
 intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hai");     
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"+"1234567890"));
   //intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

It is working but after sending sms, its not returning back to my activity. If I put intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true); then sms body is showing empty in sms composer.

I want showing content in composer and it should return back to my activity after sending sms.
Any way to implement this??

Comment: did you wrote code for onactivity result correctly

Comment: yes I implemented for OnActivityResult too.

Comment: It seems that the Native SMS Composer does not set `RESULT_OK` which is why it does not return to your activity after a message is sent.

Comment: Did this get work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"+"1234567890"));
intent.putExtra("address", "1234567890");
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hai");
intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, INVITE_COMPLETED);
```

Comment: Its what I mentioned above.

Comment: @Asraf You have to supply a request code when calling a subactivity. INVITE_COMPLETED sounds a bit like it could represent a result code.

Comment: I tried using this.. but still Its not returning back to activity or not getting success result(RESULT_OK).

Answer (score 0):

native sms composer return `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` as resultCode , which you can find in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)` . No way to find whether message is sent or not.

Comment: Is there any android documentation regarding this?

Comment: Hopefully not. @MandeepSingh